# iterar un array de objetos clave valor y extraer informacion dinamica

Tags: javascript

Tengo que extraer de la variable **datos** la siguiente informacion

La información de las cuotas se debe mostrar por grupos de cuotas consecutivas (todos los nros de cuotas son consecutivos, sin huecos).
Para cada grupo de cuotas se debe mostrar:
Rango de nros. de cuota, indicando el nro de cuota más pequeño y el mayor separados por un guión.
Importe total del rango
Los grupos de cuotas consecutivas se deben mostrar ordenados en forma ascendente según el rango de cuotas.
Al final, se debe mostrar el total general del importe de cuotas adeudadas

Para los datos indicados al inicio del ejercicio, se debe mostrar exactamente esto:
(tomando en cuenta que los datos son dinamicos, es decir puede probarse con otros numeros de cuotas)

Cuotas Pendientes: 2 - 3
Importe adeudado:  $1135.69

Cuotas Pendientes: 7 - 9
Importe adeudado:  $1035.93

Cuotas Pendientes: 11 - 14
Importe adeudado:  $2482.70

```
var datos = {
    cuenta: "123456",
    nombre: "Juan",
    apellido: "Pérez",
    cuotas: [
        { cuota: 13, importe: 123.4567 },
        { cuota: 7, importe: 234.5678 },
        { cuota: 2, importe: 456.7890 },
        { cuota: 11, importe: 567.8901 },
        { cuota: 3, importe: 678.9012 },
        { cuota: 9, importe: 789.0123 },
        { cuota: 12, importe: 890.1234 },
        { cuota: 14, importe: 901.2345 },
        { cuota: 8, importe: 22.3456 }
    ]
}
```

intente acceder a cuotas al menos pero no pude avanzar mas que esto, alguien me puede ayudar

```
Object.keys(datos.cuotas).forEach((o,i)=>{
 console.log(i,datos.cuotas[o])
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

aca te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de:

- como ordenar tu array de cuotas. sort()
- como obtener solo las cuotas dentro del rango correspondiente. filter()
- como sumar todas las propiedades de un array de objetos. reduce()

creo que con eso podrias resolver tu tarea.

```js
var datos = {
  cuenta: "123456",
  nombre: "Juan",
  apellido: "Pérez",
  cuotas: [{
      cuota: 13,
      importe: 123.4567
    },
    {
      cuota: 7,
      importe: 234.5678
    },
    {
      cuota: 2,
      importe: 456.7890
    },
    {
      cuota: 11,
      importe: 567.8901
    },
    {
      cuota: 3,
      importe: 678.9012
    },
    {
      cuota: 9,
      importe: 789.0123
    },
    {
      cuota: 12,
      importe: 890.1234
    },
    {
      cuota: 14,
      importe: 901.2345
    },
    {
      cuota: 8,
      importe: 22.3456
    }
  ]
}

let cuotas = datos.cuotas.sort((a, b) => b.cuota - a.cuota)


const adedudadas = (c_A, c_B) => cuotas.filter(cuota => (cuota.cuota >= c_A) && (cuota.cuota <= c_B))

const deuda = (adeuda) => adeuda.reduce((a, b) => a + b.importe, 0)

console.log(`debe de la 2-3 un total de : ${deuda(adedudadas(2,3))}`)

console.log(`debe de la 7-8 un total de : ${deuda(adedudadas(7,8))}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Si mal no entendí se requiere obtener el importe total de cierto rango de cuotas, para eso pude hacer la solución

```js
var datos = {
    cuenta: "123456",
    nombre: "Juan",
    apellido: "Pérez",
    cuotas: [
        { cuota: 13, importe: 123.4567 },
        { cuota: 7, importe: 234.5678 },
        { cuota: 2, importe: 456.7890 },
        { cuota: 11, importe: 567.8901 },
        { cuota: 3, importe: 678.9012 },
        { cuota: 9, importe: 789.0123 },
        { cuota: 12, importe: 890.1234 },
        { cuota: 14, importe: 901.2345 },
        { cuota: 8, importe: 22.3456 }
    ]
}
const cuotasPendientes = (rango) => {
  const min = parseInt(rango.split('-')[0]);
  const max = parseInt(rango.split('-')[1]);
  const isInRange = (cuotas) => cuotas >= min && cuotas <= max;
  const cuotasEnRango = datos.cuotas.filter(c => isInRange(c.cuota));
  let importeTotal = 0;
  cuotasEnRango.forEach(c => importeTotal += c.importe)
  return importeTotal;
}
console.log(cuotasPendientes("1-3"))
```